# How to make sure that created node will exist and will be unique in Memgraph?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

If I get it correctly, this only enforces an existence constraint, not a uniqueness:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:City)
ASSERT exists (c.name);
```

To make it unique, I would use a unique property constraint using the following syntax:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:City)
ASSERT c.name IS UNIQUE
```

Can I somehow make it unique and enforce existence at the same time?

If I run:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:City)
ASSERT exists (c.name) IS UNIQUE;
```

I get an error:

```
Query failed: line 2:24 mismatched input 'IS' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}
```

Comment: You could try creating 2 separate constraints (one UNIQUE, and one EXISTS). I am not sure if memgraph allows that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment due to my low karma, but @cybersam is correct. If you want to make it clear that you're enforcing both existence and uniqueness, you can use a combination of `ASSERT EXISTS` and `ASSERT c.property IS UNIQUE`. This syntax is not  supported by Cypher in a single statement.

To achieve both constraints, you will need to create two separate queries. One for existence and one for uniqueness.

Frist query:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:City)
ASSERT EXISTS (c.name);
```

Second query:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:City)
ASSERT c.name IS UNIQUE;
```